# Possible to reset SMART logs?

Tags: smart

I got two 2TB seagate disks that show SMART error on bootup.  I ran the seagate disk utility check and it passed the full test. But the SMART error says both drive have exceeded 70C in temperature so SMART has been tripped. I want to recycle them for old hardware as they are out of warranty.

Answer (score 1):

No.

S.M.A.R.T. attributes are made to be prevented from being altered with.

The S.M.A.R.T. system is maintained by the drive itself, so you cannot normally "reset" or "clear" SMART values. That, if possible in practice, your defeat part of its purpose.

You could in theory download the corresponding micro-code, alter what you need and re-write it, but that has a good chance of bricking your HDD. I'm sure there are some hack-around things that would do it, but most likely those would work on a very limited number of drives and present the risk I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't need to. If something new happens it will be in the logs with the new timestamp (hours powered on).